# Progress Bar inside a Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

Is it possible with bootstrap to create an effect like the image bellow?

[image]

An example: Think about the 86% being 100% of itself. The lighter bar would show the percentagem of 86%. The lighter bar will not have value to show, I am thinking in add it as a tooltip.

The code I have so far is something like this:

```
<div class="container top-padding-low">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 14%">14%</div>
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 86%">86%<span style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_BIB8LalXabo/TL9sCQSCL8I/AAAAAAAAARQ/cJWQTkKYqFk/s1600/BlueSquare.gif" style="height: 10px; width: 30%;"></span></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swpy498f/

UPDATE:

```
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 14%">14%</div>
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 86%">86%
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 30%">30%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The result is:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/swpy498f/1/

Comment: Sure, have two divs inside the main, and keep adjusting their width appropriately

Comment: You just blew my mind. What is this? Progress bar inception?

Comment: ^ yeah, a progress bar inside a progress bar : )

Comment: Just from a UX perspective, this is a pretty incomprehensible way to display data.

Comment: @thomas, In the context I am applying it, it will make more sense.